# Sidekiq web panel shows forbidden

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, sidekiq

I have mounted the Sidekiq panel in my Sinatra app like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'sidekiq/web'

env = ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym || :development

Bundler.require(:default, :sinatra, env)
disable :run
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8

set :environment, env

use Rack::ShowExceptions
use Rack::Session::Pool
use Rack::MethodOverride

Sidekiq::Web.use Rack::Session::Pool

require File.expand_path '../app/my_app.rb', __FILE__
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => MyApp.new, "/sidekiq" => Sidekiq::Web.new)
```

This means my app is accessible through `/` and the sidekiq web panel through `/sidekiq`.

Now when I try to delete a job, I always get `Forbidden`. I read here https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1289 and here https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2487 but wether upgrading to `rack-protection > 1.5.1` nor setting a session for `Sidekiq::Web` has solved the problem so far.

I'm starting my server with `rackup` using WEBrick, so I think this shouldn't be a server problem.

I'm using sinatra 1.4.2 with sidekiq 3.5.1. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Haven't found a solution so far. One thing I noticed as I tried out the sidekiq-failures gem (https://github.com/mhfs/sidekiq-failures) that it shows the same behaviour `Forbidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. First I updated from sidekiq 3.4.2 to 4.0.1 and from sinatra 1.4.2 to 1.4.6. No problems so far.

The problem with the `Forbidden` message was a missing authenticity token for sidekiq's web panel. By adding the following lines, it worked:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'sidekiq/web'

#####################################
# added a require for rack/protection
require 'rack/protection'
#####################################

env = ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym || :development

Bundler.require(:default, :sinatra, env)
disable :run
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8

set :environment, env

use Rack::ShowExceptions
use Rack::Session::Pool
use Rack::MethodOverride
#####################################
# tell sinatra to use rack's protection methods
use Rack::Protection
#####################################

require File.expand_path '../app/my_app.rb', __FILE__
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => MyApp.new, "/sidekiq" => Sidekiq::Web.new)
```

Also have a look at https://github.com/sinatra/rack-protection where all the protection methods are listed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add this to application.rb (or an initializer like config/initializers/sidekiq.rb):

```
Sidekiq::Web.instance_variable_get(:@middleware).delete_if do |middleware|
  middleware.first == Rack::Protection
end
```

That comes from a [recent commit](https://github.com/transitland/transitland-datastore/pull/605/commits/e92ec248dda1f45e8e83bb9c4692efff9ee5ae2c), but it's only applied to production and staging environments.

*[Detailed explanation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1289) about this problem.*